# validations on html.dropdownlist in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, drop-down-menu

How shall I perform validations on the `Html.Dropdownlist` in my mvc application,Please tell what shall I do.

Thanks
Ritz

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this part](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm) of nerd dinner tutorial to get a understanding of how to add validations.

Thanks